# Regex to match different characters at same position in string

Tags: regex

Let's say I have the text a123456. I want a string of b123456 to match. So essentially, 'match if all characters are the same except for the first character'. Am I asking for the impossible with regex?

Comment: Of course: use `.` to match any character. So `^.123456$` shoud do the job.

Comment: What flavor of regex?  A regex pattern that matches that sequence of numbers following a character would be `/^.123456$/` theoretically.

Comment: But of course, comparing a substring of both starting at character 1 would be easier...

Comment: Sorry, this one is a little confusing. My problem is that the incoming string is already fully defined. It's a query involving doing a regex match with a database. So say, I have 'a123456' in a column of the database, and I have a variable 'x' that contains 'b123456'. I run REGEXP_LIKE(<column>, x). I can interpolate regular expressions in front and behind x, for example, REGEXP_LIKE(<column>, '.'+x+'[0-9]{2}'). I suppose I may need to run a separate query where I trim the leading character off x.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dot (.) to match any character. So, a possible Regex would be:

```
  /^.123456$/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [zero length assertion with regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can have `lookbehind` approach in following way :

```
(?<=\w)your_value$ // your_value should be text which you want to check
```

Comment: See my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862723/regex-to-match-different-characters-at-same-position-in-string#comment70909551_41862723). My problem is that my comparison string already has the mismatched character.

Comment: you can achieve with above regex what you've specified in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can figure it out on your own. This ain't tough, just needs some understanding between you and Regex. Why don't you go through the following links and try to make a regex on your own.

https://www.talentcookie.com/2015/07/regular-expressions/

https://www.talentcookie.com/2015/07/lets-practice-regular-expression/

https://www.talentcookie.com/2016/01/some-useful-regular-expression-terminologies/